# Request status update Twitter stream data

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, python-twitter

I retrieved Twitter data via the streaming API on Python, however, I am also interested in how the public metrics evolve during the time. As a result, I would like to request on a daily basis the metrics.

Unfortunately, the API for the status update can only handle 100 requests at a time. I have a list of all id's, how is it possible to automatically split the string of id's so that all of them will be requested, always in batches of 100?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: don't keep as single string but as a list of IDs (strings). When you have list then you can use `my_list[0:100]`, `my_list[100:200]`, ... `my_list[n:n+100]` - so you can use `for`-loop like `for n in range(0, len(my_list), 100): print( my_list[n:n+100] )`. And then you can even convert list to string if you need it `",".join(my_list[n:n+100])`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it as list of IDs instead of single string.

And then you can use `range(len(...))` with `[n:n+100]` like

```
# example data
all_ids = list(range(500))

SIZE = 100
#SIZE = 10  # test on smaller size

for n in range(0, len(all_ids), SIZE):
    print(all_ids[n:n+SIZE])
```

You can even use `yield` to create special function for this

```
def split(data, size):
    for n in range(0, len(data), size):
        yield data[n:n+size]

# example data
all_ids = list(range(500))

SIZE = 100
SIZE = 10
    
for part in split(all_ids, SIZE):
    print(part)
```

---

Eventually you can get `[:100]` and slice `[100:]` but this destroy list so you have to do it on copy of this list

```
# example data
all_ids = list(range(500))

SIZE = 100
#SIZE = 10  # test on smaller size

all_ids_copy = all_ids.copy()

while all_ids_copy:
    print(all_ids_copy[:SIZE])
    all_ids_copy = all_ids_copy[SIZE:]
```

---

You can also use some external modules for this.

```
from toolz import partition

# example data
all_ids = list(range(500))

SIZE = 100
#SIZE = 10  # test on smaller size
 
for part in partition(SIZE, all_ids):
    print(part)
```

---

If you will have list of strings then you can convert back to single string using `join()`

```
    print( ",".join(part) )
```

For list of integers you may need to convert integers to strings

```
    print( ",".join(str(x) for x in part) )
```